# Is it more efficient to reset a counter or let it increase and use modulo

Tags: java, c++, performance, coding-style

Say you need to track the number of times a method is called and print something when it has been called n times. What would be the most efficient:

1. Use a long variable _counter and increase it each time the method is called. Each call you test for the equality "_counter % n == 0"
2. Use an int variable _counter and increase it each time the method is called. When _counter = n, print the message and reset the variable _counter to 0.

Some would say the difference is negligible and you are probably right. I am just curious of what method is most commonly used

Comment: This is a micro optimization, but I would go for the 2nd option.

Comment: I think, I would go for int in this situation, int would be suffice.

Comment: 2nd Option would be faster..Why? because u are not doing any mathematical calculation there.

Comment: Well the options have different results because the first might overflow.

Comment: @VishalK - without knowing the OP's platform, it's impossible to say that the integer division required by option #1 is faster or slower than the branch misprediction implied by option #2. This is one reason why micro-optimizations should be avoided.

Comment: @parsifal: Can u elaborate how branch misprediction could occur in option#2.?

Comment: Whichever is more readable by a human is the better approach. Performance wise they are equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, since you need to have an if-statement ANYWAY, I would say that you should just set it to zero when it reaches the count.

However, for a case where you use the value every time, and just want to "wrap round to zero when we reach a certain value", then the case is less obvious.

If you can adjust `n` to be a power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ...), then you can use the trick of `counter % n` is the same as `counter & (n-1)` - which makes the operation REALLY quick.

If `n` is not a power of two, then chances are that you end up doing a real divide, which is a bad idea - divide is very expensive, compared to regular instructions, and a compare and reset is highly likely faster than the divide option.

Of course, as others have mentioned, if your counter ever reaches the MAX limit for the type, you could end up with all manner of fun and games.

Edit: And of course, if you are printing something, that probably takes 100 times longer than the divide, so it really is micro-optimization, unless `n` is quite large.

Comment: It depends whether `n` is a constant, too. If it is then the compiler won't do a divide (if the optimizer is any good). In both C++ and Java it's *possible* to run unoptimized code, but not encouraged ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value of n... but I bet resetting and a simple equality check is faster.
Additionally resetting the counter is safer, you will never reach the representation limit for your number.
Edit: also consider readability, doing micro optimizations may obscure your code.

Comment: Your second sentence is the reason to use this approach. The first depends heavily on processor architecture, which we know nothing about.

Comment: Yes you never know what happens behind the scenes, but usually a simple equality check is really efficient because it is a common operation.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction for why it might not be "really efficient." Integer math is also a "common operation."

Answer (score 1):

Why not do both.

If it becomes a problem then look to see if it is worth optimizing.
But there is no point even looking at it until it is a problem (there will be much bigger problems in your algorithms).

```
count = (count+1) % countMax;
```

Comment: You mean `count = (count + 1) %countMax;` as updating and assigning the variable in the same statement is UB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is always better to reset the counter for the following reasons:

1. The code is clearer to an unfamiliar programmer (for example, the maintenance programmer).
2. There is less chance of an arithmetic (perhaps bad spelling) overflow when you reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Inspection of [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) RateLimiter will give you some idea of a similar utility implementation  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are performance times for 100000000 iterations, in ms

modTime = 1258

counterTime = 449

po2Time = 108

As we see Power of 2 outperforms other methods by far, but its only for powers of 2, also our plain counter is almost 2.5 times faster than modulus as well. So why would we like to use modulus increments at all? Well in my opinion I think they provide a clean code and if used properly they are a great tool to know of

[original post](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=204)

Comment: That test is flawed. It does all three test cases in a single JVM invocation. The third test will have the benefit of the first test having warmed up the JVM. Change the order and the results will change.

Comment: @SteveKuo: Thanks I will do that,  I will use a average of multiple runs instead of just start/end for one run.